# Debugging XSLT in Chrome

Tags: debugging, xslt, google-chrome, xslt-tools

I'm having trouble with an XSL translation in Chrome.  I was wondering if there any tools that would allow me to step through the style sheet to see where the problem is.

Comment: I think there isn't. Maybe if you ask about your specific problem we might give you an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to give specifics about my issue.  I was hoping to ask the question generally in the hopes that I can help others solve XSL problems of their own in the future.

Comment: Any kind of debugging advice would be great.

Answer (score 1):

- Use [node tests](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/nodetest.html) to check the results of XPath queries.
- Use the [document function](http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1509) to test file paths
- Use the JavaScript console to run XPath queries on the XML data source
- Use inline templates instead of `xsl:include` to eliminate path issues
- Use comments to eliminate `xsl:include` statements referencing buggy templates
- Use processing-instructions to comment blocks of code that have XML comments
- Use an [embedded stylesheet](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#embedded) to workaround same-origin policy restrictions
- Use `input` tags to print `xsl:variable` values.
- Use attribute value templates to print unknown values
- Use [simplified stylesheets](http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1243) and [parameterized XPath](http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1223) to modularize templates
- Use Opera as a cross-reference, since it shows line numbers in its XSLT error messages.

Answer (score 0):

On linux there is a tool called [xsltproc](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xsltproc) which takes an XSL and XML and outputs the transform.

It also shows context around errors.

I've found this most useful when I'm developing as I can test the result of my changes without the need to have a development server up and running. It just works.

However, I've noticed that the results of the transform can differ from that of Chrome for example. I don't know why this is, whether my transform was non-conforming, if Chrome is non-conforming, or if xsltproc is non-conforming.

**EDIT** My comment about differences between Chrome and xsltproc rendering the transform slightly differently is likely **invalid**.

- I had modified the XML schema somewhat, and since then, xsltproc was generating tags (based on type name of types in the schema) correctly, but Chrome was not.
- I was doing hard reloads to avoid Chrome reusing the cache.
- I could tell Chrome was using the new xsl as there was other changes included that were being rendered.
- Only the schema related tests were not working in Chrome for some reason.
- I've since found that now it is magically working, with no changes to the xsl, just on a different day.

So I guess some part of the xsl was being cached somehow (perhaps just the schema bit - totally guessing here)... hence why some debugging in Chrome would be super nice.

Comment: What kind of difference do you notice? AFAIK, Chrome uses the `libxslt` processor, which is also used by `zsltproc` - so any differences should be very minor, possibly due to different versions. --- In general, the XSLT specifications leave several things as "implementation dependent"  - so a difference in behavior does not necessarily mean non-conformance.

Comment: Thanks for asking, I need to follow up on this. I'll edit my answer to clarify.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) You should vote to close this old question, not answer it. [answer]

Comment: I have no interest in voting to close this question. My extensive internet searching ended up here, and to another similar question which I linked back to this. I think it's good to have all the answers to this question in one place wouldn't you agree?